# Can you put an object into a global constant in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm reviewing some old code and it looks odd.
I have file named "defines.py"
In it are a bunch of classes, most with strings, one with some objects.

```
class ITEM:
    SUB_ITEM_1 =1
    SUB_ITEM_2 = form.widget()
```

Of course there's some weirdness displaying the form.widget because you can't assign a object to a "constant", can you?

Comment: What do you mean by "can"? It's not a good practice but python won't complain.

Comment: Right, so WHY isn't it a good practice? And by CAN , it's assumed, "Do it without any weird behavior". Clearly it doesnt throw any errors, but are there any side effects?

Comment: Using all capital variable as constant is just a tradition people used. There is no constraint on it by python at all. Python will just treat it as a regular variable. It's not a good practice because it confuses other people.